# Retrieve entry greater than an other one

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an entity : Stats.

There are 5 fields in the stat entity (col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5).

There are some values in my entity such as

```
------------------------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col4 |
------------------------------------
|  13  |  15  |  17  |  10  |   4  |   
|  30  |   5  |  19  |  20  |   5  |   
|  10  |  10  |   7  |  30  |   6  |   
|  15  |  25  |  12  |  12  |  10  |   
|  17  |  14  |  14  |  11  |  40  |   
------------------------------------
```

I have an array (dimension 5) with 5 values (10,14,10,5,1) and I would like to retrieve all lines which are grater than my array.

With this example I want to retrieve

```
------------------------------------
|  13  |  15  |  17  |  10  |   4  |    
|  15  |  25  |  12  |  12  |  10  |     
------------------------------------
```

I've made

```
SELECT * from myEntity where col1>tab1 AND col2>tab2 AND col3>tab3 ....
```

But my question is : is there an more convenient way ? 
If I have 20 cols in my entity ?

EDIT :

If there is an convenient way to order by col1, col2, col3 ....
Is that a good idea to

1. insert the array in the entity,
2. order the entity,
3. retrieve all entries before this new entry
4. delete the entry

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: What do you mean with "more convenient"? All the values and all the column names must appear in any case.

Comment: yeah "more convenient" means : no need to list all column names, there is no way to avoid this ?

Comment: How should SQLite know which columns you want to compare when you don't list them?